# @GroupSequenceProvider and group is a superset

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Simple class Person.class

```
class Person {

@NotNull(groups = {PartlyCheck.class})
private String name;

@NotNull(groups = {FullCheck.class})
private String adress;

private boolean isFullCheck;

}
```

Check interfaces

```
public interface PartlyCheck{}
public interface FullCheck extends PartlyCheck{}
```

I use two approach:

```
    if(person.isFullCheck) {

      validator.validate(person, FullCheck.class);

    else {

       validator.validate(person, PartlyCheck.class);
  }
```

1.

If isFullCheck=true used both checks (FullCheck.class and PartlyCheck.class)

If isFullCheck=false used only PartlyCheck.class.

It is an understandable behavior.

```
    @GroupSequenceProvider(PersonGroupSequenceProvider.class)

    @Override
    public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(Person person) {                

       List<Class<?>> defaultGroupSequence = new ArrayList<>();
       defaultGroupSequence.add(Person.class);                    


        if (person.isFullCheck) {                                
            defaultGroupSequence.add(FullCheck.class);
        } else {                                
            defaultGroupSequence.add(PartlyCheck.class);
        }       


       return defaultGroupSequence;
   }
```

1. In the second case, I added @GroupSequenceProvider(PersonGroupSequenceProvider.class).

If isFullCheck=true used only FullCheck.class.

**Why extends is not considered for this case?**

If isFullCheck=false used only PartlyCheck.class.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? I am not quite sure what you are asking. What does not work as expected and how does the problem manifest itself?

Comment: bean validation spec: "For a given interface Z, constraints marked as belonging to the group Z (i.e. where the annotation element groups constraint declaration and validation process contains the interface Z) or any of the super interfaces of Z (inherited groups) are considered part of the group Z." But when I assign the group through @GroupSequenceProvider it does not work.

Comment: bean_validation-1.0 spec, page 27, "3.4.1. Group inheritance"/Example 3.3. Groups can inherit other groups

Comment: If you think it is a bug in Hibernate Validator I suggest you open an issue in their bug tracker - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV. If possible with a test case.

Comment: @Hardy, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168964/bean-validation-group-inheritance-isnt-working-with-group-sequence-provider