# Bean Validation Group inheritance isn't working with Group Sequence Provider

Tags: java, validation, inheritance, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm currently working on implementing an application that stores contact information which contains both foreign and domestic addresses, but the addresses can also be disabled.

I have attempted to define three validation groups: a super group for the always validated info and two child classes for the different address states.

```
public interface ContactValidation {}
public interface DomesticValidation extends ContactValidation {}
public interface ForeignValidation extends ContactValidation {}
```

I then defined an @GroupSequenceProvider on the contact class.

```
public class ContactGroupSequenceProvider implements DefaultGroupSequenceProvider<Contact> {

@Override
public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(Contact contact) {
    List<Class<?>> defaultGroupSequence = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

    if(contact.getIsForeign()){
        defaultGroupSequence.add(Contact.ForeignValidation.class);
    } else {
        defaultGroupSequence.add(Contact.DomesticValidation.class);
    } //TODO: Add Address Disabled Case

    defaultGroupSequence.add(Contact.class); //Get a GroupDefinitionException without this line

    return defaultGroupSequence;
}
```

When I run the program with either address validation, the fields marked with groups=Contact.ContactValidation.class are not being validated even though it is a super class of the address validations.

I need this application to validate together so the used doesn't have to fix an error, submit and get the new errors.

I also would like to avoid solutions with the always validated fields being like this.

```
@NotBlank(groups={DomesticValidation.class,ForeignValidation.class ,ContactValidation.class})   
private String fullContactName;
```

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: My question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363481/groupsequenceprovider-and-group-is-a-superset
Version 4.3.1.Final has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return one of the sub-classes, I'd also expect the constraints tagged with `ContactValidation` to be validated. This seems to be a bug in Hibernate Validator, so could you open a ticket in our [issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV/)?

As a work-around you might try to explicitly add `ContactValidation` to the list you return.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if it's a bug then I will just work around it for now. My company is currently using version 4.2.0 version of Hibernate. Do you know if this issue is fixed in a later version? Otherwise I will open a ticket for it.

Comment: I don't remember any fix in this area out of my head, but if you could test it with 5.1 and create an issue if it still exists, that'd be very helpful.